# Vue: Update image in firestore and firebase cloud storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I am working on the food delivery e-commerce project using vue.js and firestore.

Now I have two fields in my "Product" collection. One field is for the store building image called storefront, and the other field is for food sample picture called sample.

The data structure is like the screenshot below.
[image]

I have already uploaded those images, but also I want to update the pictures in the user profile edit page.

What I want to achieve is, to update "Product" collection fields, and also update the pictures in the cloud storage.

I want to know how I can achieve this.

Pictures.vue

The first three methods are for the "storefront" picture, and the others are for the "sample" picture.

template field

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="ml-5 mb-5 picture-size">
            <span>The pictures has to be up to 800px X 1000px</span>
        </div>
        
        <b-container class="bv-example-row">
            <b-row>
                <b-col md="6" class="">
                    <p>Storefront picture</p>
                       <div class="image-area" v-for="(storefront, index) in product.storefronts" v-bind:key="index" >
                          
                            <img :src="storefront" alt="" class="picture">
                           
                        </div>
                        <div v-if="uploadStatusStorefront" class="upload">
                             <input type="file"  name="imageSample" @change="uploadStorefront" id="file" accept="image/*">
                                <label for="file" class="Upload-image">
                                    Upload
                                </label>
                        </div>
                    
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center m-3">
                        <div v-if="showStorefront">
                            <b-button class="loginbutton-color" type="submit">
                                <spring-spinner
                                    :animation-duration="3000"
                                    :size="27"
                                    color="#ff1d5e"
                                    class="loading"
                                />
                            </b-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </b-col>
                 <b-col md="6" class="">
                    <p>Sample picture</p>
                       <div class="image-area" v-for="(sample, index) in product.samples" v-bind:key="index" >
                          
                            <img :src="sample" alt="" class="picture">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div v-if="uploadStatusSample" class="upload">
                             <input type="file"  name="imageStorefront" @change="uploadSample" id="file" accept="image/*">
                                <label for="file" class="Upload-image">
                                    Upload
                                </label>
                        </div>
                    
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center m-3">
                        <div v-if="showSample">
                            <b-button class="loginbutton-color" type="submit">
                                <spring-spinner
                                    :animation-duration="3000"
                                    :size="27"
                                    color="#ff1d5e"
                                    class="loading"
                                />
                            </b-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
        </b-container>
        
    </div>
</template>
```

script field

```
<script>
import ErrorBar from '@/components/ErrorBar'
import { SpringSpinner } from 'epic-spinners'
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
const db = firebase.firestore();

    export default {
        name: "Pictures",
    data() {
      return {
        showStorefront: false,
        showSample: false,
        deleteStatusStorefront: true,
        deleteStatusSample: true,
        uploadStatusStorefront: true,
        uploadStatusSample: true,
        show: false,
        product: {
            storefronts: "",
            samples: ""
        }
      }
    },
    components: {
        SpringSpinner
    },
    created() {
        let ref = db.collection('Product').doc(this.$route.params.id)
        ref.get()
        .then(doc => {  //Docdoc
              if (doc.exists) {
                this.product.storefronts = doc.data().storefront
                console.log(this.product.storefronts)

                this.product.samples = doc.data().sample
                console.log(this.product.samples)
                
              } else {
                  console.log("No such document!");
              }  
        })
             
    },
    methods: {
            uploadStorefront(e) {
                if(e.target.files[0]) {
                    this.showStorefront = true
                    console.log('a')
                    let file = e.target.files[0];
                    var storageRef = fireApp.storage().ref('ProUser/'+ Math.random() + '_'  + file.name);//uniquenameにする
                    let uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);
                    uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
                    }, (error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    }, () => {
                        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
                        this.product.storefronts.push(downloadURL)
                        this.storefrontSubmit()
                        this.storefrontSubmitProduct()
                        this.showStorefront = false
                        this.deleteStatusStorefront = true
                        this.uploadStatusStorefront = false
                        });
                    });
                }
            },


            storefrontSubmit() {
                var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                var docRef = db.collection('ProUser').doc(user.uid)
                docRef.get().then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        console.log(this.product.storefronts)
                        docRef.update({ 
                            storefront: this.product.storefronts
                        })
                    } 
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
            },

            storefrontSubmitProduct() {
                var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                var docRef = db.collection('Product').doc(user.uid)
                docRef.get().then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        docRef.update({ 
                            storefront: this.product.storefronts
                        })
                    } else {
                        docRef.set({ 
                            storefront: this.product.storefronts
                        }, { merge: true })
                        
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
            
            },

            uploadSample(e) {
                if(e.target.files[0]) {
                    this.showSample = true
                    let file = e.target.files[0];
                    var storageRef = fireApp.storage().ref('Sample/'+ Math.random() + '_'  + file.name);//uniquenameにする
                    let uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);
                    uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
                    }, (error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    }, () => {
                        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
                        this.product.samples.push(downloadURL)
                        this.sampleSubmit()
                        this.showSample = false
                        this.deleteStatusSample = true
                        this.uploadStatusStorefront = false
                        });
                    });
                }
            },

            sampleSubmit() {
                var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                console.log('aaaaa')
                var docRef = db.collection('Product').doc(user.uid)
                docRef.get().then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        docRef.update({ 
                            sample: this.product.samples
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                            this.show = false
                        })
                    } else {
                        docRef.set({ 
                            sample: this.product.samples
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                            this.show = false
                        })
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
            });
            },

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any chance you could phrase your question differently? Don't use your app-specific terminology, just describe the situation and what isn't working in normal words. (I think you might be looking for the firebase storage triggers and cloud functions, but I am not sure because your question isn't entirely clear)

Comment: I edited. If you need more information, please feel free to ask me.

Comment: I have tried, but your question is just a bit too vague to really understand what is going on. Just imagine I am a busy colleague who doesn't know anything about your project, and you quickly want to summarise what you are doing and which problem you encountered https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: here's a question that was well structured: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675731/unable-to-add-data-to-custom-user-collection-properly-in-firestore

Comment: Thank you, I’ll fix my question to make my question obvious. Actually I am building e-commerce project.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what is not working for you? What is the error message?

Comment: I updated my question again, so please check it out. If you still have any unclear point, please ask me. I will answer for your question. Thank you.

Comment: I see your code but what exactly is not working? Which part of it? Does the image not get uploaded into Storage? If so what is the error message?

Comment: @EmilGi I have already uploaded the images in the collection and the cloud storage as I wrote in the question. What I want to do is to update those images. I can upload the images, but I cannot figure out how I can do it.